# Pandas: efficient way to replace entire string with a substring

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['John','William', 'Nancy', 'Susan', 'Robert', 'Lucy', 'Blake', 'Sally', 'Bruce'],
    'injury': ['right hand broken', 'lacerated left foot', 'foot broken', 'right foot fractured', '', 'sprained finger', 'chest pain', 'swelling in arm', 'laceration to arms, hands, and foot']
    })


    name      injury
0   John      right hand broken
1   William   lacerated left foot
2   Nancy     foot broken
3   Susan     right foot fractured
4   Robert  
5   Lucy      sprained finger
6   Blake     chest pain
7   Sally     swelling in arm
8   Bruce     lacerations to arm, hands, and foot      <-- this is a weird case, since there are multiple body parts
```

Notably, some of the values in the `injury` column are blank.

I want to replace the values in the `injury` column with ***only the affected body part***.  In my case, that would be hand, foot, finger, and chest, arm.  There are dozens more... this is a small example.

The desired dataframe would look like this:

```
    name      injury
0   John      hand
1   William   foot
2   Nancy     foot
3   Susan     foot
4   Robert  
5   Lucy      finger
6   Blake     chest
7   Sally     arm
8   Bruce     arm, hand, foot
```

I could do something like this:

```
df.loc[df['injury'].str.contains('hand'), 'injury'] = 'hand'
df.loc[df['injury'].str.contains('foot'), 'injury'] = 'foot'
df.loc[df['injury'].str.contains('finger'), 'injury'] = 'finger'
df.loc[df['injury'].str.contains('chest'), 'injury'] = 'chest'
df.loc[df['injury'].str.contains('arm'), 'injury'] = 'arm'
```

But, this might not be the most elegant way.

Is there a more elegant way to do this?  (e.g. using a dictionary)

(any advice on that last case with multiple body parts would be appreciated)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you should maintain a list of text, and using apply function:

```
body_parts = ['hand', 'foot', 'finger', 'chest', 'arm']
def test(value):
    body_text = []
    for body_part in body_parts:
        if body_part in value:
             body_text.append(body_part)
    if body_text:
        return ', '.join(body_text)
    return value
df['injury'] = df['injury'].apply(test)
```

return:

```
name    injury
0   John    hand
1   William foot
2   Nancy   foot
3   Susan   foot
4   Robert  
5   Lucy    finger
6   Blake   chest
7   Sally   arm
8   Bruce   hand, foot, arm
```

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to **get the first match of a regex on a string column** is to use `.extract()`, please see the quickstart [10 minutes to pandas: working with text data](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/text.html).

```
df['injury'].str.extract('(arm|chest|finger|foot|hand)', expand=False)

0      hand
1      foot
2      foot
3      foot
4       NaN
5    finger
6     chest
7       arm
8       arm
Name: injury, dtype: object
```

Note row 4 returned NaN rather than '' (but it's trivial to apply `.fillna('')` to the result). More importantly in row 8 we'll only return the first match, not all matches. You need to decide how you want to handle this. See `.extractall()`

Answer (score 0):

```
selected_words = ["hand", "foot", "finger", "chest", "arms", "arm", "hands"]

df["injury"] = (
    df["injury"]
    .str.replace(",", "")
    .str.split(" ", expand=False)
    .apply(lambda x: ", ".join(set([i for i in x if i in selected_words])))
)
print(df)

      name             injury
0     John               hand
1  William               foot
2    Nancy               foot
3    Susan               foot
4   Robert                   
5     Lucy             finger
6    Blake              chest
7    Sally                arm
8    Bruce  arms, foot, hands
```

Comment: Extending the solution by @Jason Baker to:  `.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(set([i for i in x if i in selected_body_parts and i not np.nan else np.nan])))`, I'm getting a syntax error.  I'd like to check for NaN values (because there are some), and output NaN if the list comprehension encounters a case that's not in the list of `selected_words`.